# How to check if user is logged in using class based custom middleware?

Tags: python, django, web

I want to redirect not logged in users to login page every request they do. I have a custom class based middleware. I found on stackoverflow a solution to the problem using function based middleware. When I try to use this function inside my class, it doesn't work. But if I remove class and leave the function, it works fine. How can I fix this problem?

```
# class based
class CustomMidd:
    def __init__ (self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        self.check_user(request)
        self.process_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
    
    # def process_request(self, request):
    #    allowed_ips = ['127.0.0.1'] # my ip
    #    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    #    if ip not in allowed_ips:
    #        raise Http404
    #    return None
    
    def check_user(self,request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated or request.path == '/login/':
            response = self.get_response(request)
            return response
        return redirect('/login/')


# function based
def require_login(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated or request.path == '/login/':
            response = get_response(request)
            return response
        return redirect('/login/')
    return middleware
```

It should also raise 404 error if ip is not allowed. So if I leave only function, it works, but I can't check ip now.

When I try to enter main page, it returns an error `Field 'id' expected a number but got...`. This is because at the start of `views.main` I get `request.user`. It means that it doesn't redirect me to login. What can I do?